# Making sure googlebot is not spamming my mailbox

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

I have got a website running with an option to report abuse of functionality. This is being done by clicking a link. After the link is clicked the webmaster will get a report of the location where the content is that was reported as abuse. I have added an rel="NOFOLLOW" to the href of the particular links but this is not helping. It seems that this tag is only being used to check wheter a page has to be ranked or not. How can i Exclude googlebot from clicking those abuse links?

This is what a link looks like:

```
<a href="domainname.com/blaat.aspx?reportabuse={5478957234234289347}">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would go is have the report abuse email be behind a POST form of some kind. For example, a drop down box to select the issue or a text box to write in some comment about the abuse. Another method would be to style the form submit button so that it looked like a link and use that in place of your current link if you didn't want to have another step.

Comment: Yes. A regular hyperlink (using GET) should (according to the HTTP spec) not result in actions like changing data or sending email. You'll notice that there is no href on the "flag" button here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's a plain link and the report is done after just clicking it. Is there no way to just make sure googlebot won't follow that link??

Comment: You could also use Javascript (onclick). Googlebot will not trigger them.

Comment: It's a bit more complex i should have said that aswell im affraid. It's a sitecore website. It's using C# .NET technology and i think i'll have to build in captcha validation or some other kind of verification before spamming out an e-mail for abuse.
And
@Thilo thx for your answer about the HTTP spec ;).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in two parts:

1. By default, I'd make the link take you to a page where you report the abuse via a (very short, friendly) form, one where if you don't want to, you don't even have to choose anything, just click the Report button. Clicking the Report button (or a cancel link) takes you back where you were.
2. I'd include JavaScript that would test if the user has modern browser features (DOM node creation and such) and, if so, change the action of the link so that when they click it, the form appears right there (in a small overlay box) rather than taking you to a separate page. That makes for a less-intrusive user experience. Either way, though, the end result is a form being submitted rather than simply a link being followed.